# Remove Recent from Table of Contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have a Table of Contents web part on the homepage of my Sharepoint 2016 site.  When my users create a new library, it automatically display the new library in Table of Contents.  But it shows underneath a heading, Recent.  How can I change it that the new library displays, but not underneath Recent.

Answer (score 0):

To remove (or hide) the "Recent" menu header from the left navigation of SharePoint 2013, hide "Recent" from SharePoint 2013 Quick Launch Navigation for your reference(which is also work in SharePoint 2016):

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/hide-recent-from-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch.html